# How to specify a relation on a complex type?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF code first to define two relations on a complex type with an unsuccessful result of an InvalidOperation Exception "{"The expression 'p => p.AuditInfo.CreatedBy' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'."}"

What i'm doing wrong ?

Relevant code:

```
public class AuditInfo
{
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; internal set; }
    public Guid? CreatedById { get; internal set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; internal set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; internal set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedById { get; internal set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; internal set; }

    public byte[] ModifiedTimestamp;
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; internal set; }
    public string Email { get; internal set; }

    public AuditInfo AuditInfo { get; internal set; }
}

class UserMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.HasOptional(p => p.AuditInfo.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.AuditInfo.CreatedById);
        this.HasOptional(p => p.AuditInfo.ModifiedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.AuditInfo.ModifiedById);
    }
}

public class Test3DbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<AuditInfo>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
    }
}
```

Database Table:

User { Id, Email, ..., CreatedById, ModifiedById, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complex type is treated like a value object and is appended to the end of the table that is being created. So, User will have columns Id, then email, then the AuditInfo columns. The only separation is within the code, not in the database. Therefore, complex types are tracked by their parent class, and have no foreign keys. You will need to rethink your design if you are looking for something else.

UPDATED:

If what you are looking for is just to make sure that CreatedBy/ModifiedBy is mapped for foreign key constraints, then it appears this is not possible using a ComplexType. You would have to put the full audit info in the user table.  This is specified in the [Complex Type documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx)

> Complex type cannot contain navigation properties.

Comment: i'm not understanding your answer. Physically there is only one Table, the division is only on the Model, and i don't want to manage the complexType as an "Entity" itself.

Comment: Basically, you do not need the fluent mappings, The ComplexType<AuditInfo> is good enough. If you generate the schema, you should see this work as expected. Maybe you can clarify your question a little better, and provide what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I need the mappings otherwise CreatedBy and ModifiedBy are not related to the User class, and it i'll fail to run with an Exception Duplicated User schema definition. Basically i have the existent model classes (User + Auditinfo) and i'm trying to map to the existent table User.

Comment: I am thoroughly confused now, as my previous comment SHOULD work based on what you are describing. What exactly is the error that you are getting if you try that?

Comment: If you remove the mappings the error is "System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: Each type name in a schema must be unique. Type name 'User' is already defined.". To be honest i don't know how could work without the mappings.

Comment: Well, based on the above and your descriptions, that is all you should need.  http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx If you read this blog post, it even describes that all you should need to do is mark a class as being ComplexType and any other classes that reference it will just roll it into the same table. EF will manage the identity using the parent class' id. The error you specified actually sounds like you need to rebuild the DLL's and has nothing to do with the complex type.

Comment: The error is not related to compilation, trust me. complexType registration is enough when you don't have relations , like the example: Person (E) + Address(CT).

Comment: I *think* I may understand why we are mismatching here. It sounds like you want to make sure that CreatedBy mappings are dealt with by EF? If so, then I am not entirely sure how to solve that problem. Your question is not structured as though that is what you are trying to accomplish if so, also. Complex types will have to be updated manually in the code I would think

Comment: I am reading this another way, also. If you just want to set up foreign keys inside your complex type, then this is not possible. I have updated my answer for the reasoning