# Can I define a one-to-many relationship on a complex type in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, orm

I have a situation like the following toy example:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Address> PostalAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    /* ... other properties ... */
}
```

The real situation is much more complex and I would *really* like the equivalent of the `PostalAddresses` property to be on `ContactInfo` instead of `Person`.

Is this possible using Entity Framework Code First?

---

**EDIT**

Basically, I want the above to be serialized into the following table structure:

- table: People

  - Id
  - FullName
  - ContactInfo_EmailAddress
- table: Address

  - Id
  - PersonId
  - ...

So the problem is that I need to have the `IEnumerable<Address>` collection to be on the `ContactInfo` complex type instead of the root type, `Person`. When I save a `Person` object, no `Address` rows are added to the database.

Comment: It's not that clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems perfectly clear.

I'm not an expert, but according to [How to specify a relation on a complex type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612778/how-to-specify-a-relation-on-a-complex-type) what you're trying to do is not possible. A ComplexType cannot have navigational properties.

I guess the workaround is to define ContactInfo as an entity, instead of a complex type. So ContactInfo will have a PK and it's own table.

**Maybe somebody else knows a better solution?**

By the way, I tried to do something similar. My (simplified) domain:

*Application*

- Id : int
- Candidate : Candidate
- Resume : Resume   <== I prefer to not have a separate table for this class, but how to achieve this??

*Resume*

- Experiences : [Experience]
- Trainings : [Training]

*Experience*

- Id: int
- Description: string

*Training*

- Id: int
- Description: string

*Candidate*

- Id: int
- Name: string

I ended up giving Resume an Id too, but the result is a redundant Review table consisting of just one column, i.e. the resume Id (which equals the application Id).

Comment: Thank you. I also realized that this wasn't possible. In my case, I really care about what the underlying SQL table structure looks like so I ended up creating a separate, flat data access model. I can map my domain model to it with a bit of AutoMapper magic.